# changing the nextchar timeout when "select"ing an option

Tags: html, select, timeout

This issue is best explained by example:

If I have a select box with chevy, ford and honda as options and I start type "ch" expecting to have it select "chevy", it works (if I do not pause between chars).

However, if I was too slow, the select box forgets that I typed the "c" and lands on "honda" after I type the "h".

Is there any way to control that timeout?  I would it to remember the "c" for a couple of seconds instead of something like 0.1 sec like it is now.

I know jquery and html well enough to implement any reasonably simple solution to this.

Thanks, Ron

Answer (score 0):

See , for example, [Autocomplete - jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). And using:

**JS**

```
var items= [
   "Chevy",
   "Ford",
   "Honda",
    //.. others
   ];

$("#brands").autocomplete({
  source: items,
  delay: 500
});
```

Here `delay` is setting of  timeout between keystroke occurs.

Comment: @Ron plugin `Autocomplete - jQuery UI` helped you?

Comment: Thanks voodoo417.  But I think that delay is how long it takes before autocomplete responds with the first suggestion. After that, it just waits for the next keystroke which is fine if I wanted to use autocomplete.

What I'm looking for is to lengthen the time before the normal select html element forgets what I typed.